# Adding a badge to an xpages applayout title bar node item

Tags: xpages, badge

Is it possible to add a simple badge to a title bar node item?  Each tab in my layout represents a separate application. My users would like to see a number next to the name on the tab to indicate whether there are documents in that application needing their attention.  If no documents, then no badge, just the application name by itself. If there are documents, then display the application name and a badge for the number.  I'm not finding a way to include the span tag in a PageLinkNode or BasicLinkNode.

Comment: Thanks Knut. I considered the image approach. Could you explain a little more how to implement the alternative approach?  Lastly, would you even recommend this for a 5/6 application tab app?  Adding the badge means a lookup in each app to check status with the user as the key.  I'm concerned about performance assuming each page opened will trigger the lookup again.

Comment: Don, you would parse the rendered DOM on client side and get the label elements. Use functions like `document.getElementsByClassName("lotusTabInner");`. Manipulate those elements with `document.createElement("span")` and `document.body.insertBefore(...);`

Comment: Another approach in terms of performance would be calling a REST service asynchronously on client side to get the number of unread documents. You could set a timer to do it every x seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageLinkNode (xe:pageTreeNode) label can only be **plain text**.

You can use the **image** property though:

```xml
    <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
        <xe:pageTreeNode
            page="..."
            label="Application A"
            image="#{javascript: var nr = 5; 
                        nr > 0 ? ('badge' + Math.min(nr, 10) + '.gif') : ''}">
        </xe:pageTreeNode>
```

Add to Resources/Images ten pictures badge1.gif, badge2.gif, ... badge10.gif with the numbers as pictures. badge10.gif would be a `9+` picture.

[image]

As an *alternative*, you could provide the number of documents as part of the label (e.g. "Your Application Name [23]") and convert it on client side **onClientLoad** event to HTML label + badge-span.